# How to make a cycle that change the background color every time I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, colors

I'm trying to make a static page where, if I click in any part of it, this one changes its color. I create an object with the colors hex code but I don't know how to make the `document.body.style.background` work with it.

Also, I would like it if the program can follow that secuence and not just throw random colors. Sorry if I look to the noob, but I'm new to programming. I'm learning by myself

It works if I put it like this:

```
function changeBground() {
  var colors;
  document.body.style.background = "#FF0000";
}
```

But that is only one color, is not my objective

This is my full code:

```
document.addEventListener("click", changeBground); 
var colors = {
    red: "#FF0000",
    orange: "#FF7F00",
    yellow: "FFFF00",
    green: "#00FF00",
    aqua: "#00FFFF",
    blue: "#0000FF",
    purple: "#8B00FF",
};

function changeBground()
{
  document.body.style.background = colors;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the colors keys with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method and on each click increment the index if index got colors size then set index to 0. Please try this example

```
document.addEventListener("click", changeBground);
let index = 0;
const colors = {
  red: "#FF0000",
  orange: "#FF7F00",
  yellow: "FFFF00",
  green: "#00FF00",
  aqua: "#00FFFF",
  blue: "#0000FF",
  purple: "#8B00FF",
};

function changeBground() {
  const keys = Object.keys(colors);

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[keys[index]];

  if (index < keys.length) {
    index += 1;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Here an example

```js
document.addEventListener("click", changeBground);
let index = 0;
const colors = {
  red: "#FF0000",
  orange: "#FF7F00",
  yellow: "FFFF00",
  green: "#00FF00",
  aqua: "#00FFFF",
  blue: "#0000FF",
  purple: "#8B00FF",
};

function changeBground() {
  const keys = Object.keys(colors);

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[keys[index]];

  if (index < keys.length) {
    index += 1;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: excellent, if you like it I would appreciate you select the answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning colors object to color that's why this is not working - use belo code this will work.

```
document.addEventListener("click", changeBground); 
var counter = 0;
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'aqua', 'blue', 'purple'];

function changeBground() {
  document.body.style.background = colors[counter];
  counter = counter < colors.length -1 ? counter + 1 : 0;
}
```

if you want to randomly update any color from the array use below function instead upper one -

```
function changeBground() {
  var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, man! but I still don't understand the part about "assigning colors object to color".  Also, can you please explain me how the ecuation of counter works? I never see the use of "?". I try the code and it works great but I don't understand why haha :/

Comment: @maub98: In your question you have used document.body.style.background = colors; where colors is an object while style.background is excepting name or hex code of a color followed by hash.
Second i have used " ? : " this is known as ternary operator , so for cyclic color change we need to traverse color's array from start to end and counter is helping which index we need to use for fetch color. here if index goes more than length then results in bug. So use of "?" is to check condition and update counter accordingly. Hope this clears your doubt. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! thank you for taking your time to explain me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), generate a random number that allow you to get random background color from your object combined with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), here is a working snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", changeBground); 
var colors = {
    red: "#FF0000",
    orange: "#FF7F00",
    yellow: "#FFFF00",
    green: "#00FF00",
    aqua: "#00FFFF",
    blue: "#0000FF",
    purple: "#8B00FF",
};

const colorKeys = Object.keys(colors);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function changeBground() {
  const randKey = getRandomInt(0, colorKeys.length);
  console.log(randKey, colorKeys[randKey] );
  const color = colors[colorKeys[randKey]];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. The code works and give random colors but it skips the yellow and purple, it's strange

Comment: @maub98, glad to help, its because of the random math function, will check if I can fix it.

Comment: Fixed it please try the snippet again now, the yellow color, was not included because you missed `#` in the object value, I just noticed that, and for the purple, the math function was returning exclusive value for the array length, so the last value was not included, but its fixed now.

Comment: Oh yeah, I already see that syntax error haha. And yes, it works! thank you, man!

Comment: Glad to help, Please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you any answer useful :)